Leave to Remain Start Date Discrepancy - When Can I Apply for ILR? (TIER 2)
I am planning to apply for my ILR soon but don't really know when is the earliest I can do so. Need some help figuring it out.
I received an email on September 13, 2019, stating that my Tier 2 General application was successful. However, my BRP, which I received a month later, has an issue date of October 10, 2019.
My main question is:
Given the discrepancy between the email date and the BRP issue date, what is the earliest date I can apply for ILR?
As a side question:

If I were to use the wrong date when applying for ILR, what would be the potential repercussions? Could it lead to an outright rejection of my application? Assuming I use the 13th of Sept as the start of my 5 year period instead of 10th Oct.


What was your status when you submitted the Tier 2 application?

i have this problem did you ever get an answer?
